# Чтение из файла.Нахождение строки заданной строки и идущего за ней числа

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Вот код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"rus");
    string s; int x;
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    while(1){
        f>>s;
        if(s=="Передача") { f>>x; break;}
    }
    f.close();
    cout<<s<<' '<<x<<" штук";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы находило строку "Передача" во всем файле, а следующее за ним число складывалось (х+=х), и после прохождения всего файла, выписывало бы "Передач было х(сумма всех передач)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"rus");
    string s;
    int x = 0;
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    while( f >> s ){
        if (s == "Передача" )
        {
            int v = 0;
            f >> v;
            x += v;
        }
    }
    cout <<  "Передач " << x << " штук" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Только убедитесь, что в файле текст в правильной кодировке :)

Comment: Вот как раз возник вопрос, если после слова "передача" идет число, то работает правильно, А если после слова  "передача" идет еще английский текст, то не распознается. Т.е., например строка "передача eng 55" то выводит 0 штук. А если английское слово убрать, то работает правильно. Как исправить?

Comment: Проверять результат, типа `if (f >> v) ...` и сбрасывая флаг ошибки, если таковая произошла (если пытаться читать число там, где на самом деле не оно, поток переходит в состояние `fail`).